# Ethics of Spinoza - Translation of "sit" and "satis"

Tags: translation-explanation, conjunctive, spinoza

Spinoza's ethics, On the God, Proposition 8, Scholium 2:

> ut satis attendenti sit manifestum

4 translations of this sentence:

1. White:

   > as is evident to any one who pays a little attention
2. Shirley:

   > as is obvious to anyone who gives his mind to it
3. Boyle:

   > as will be manifest to any one who regards it carefully
4. Elwes:

   > a little consideration will make this plain

They render *sit* to **is** or **will** and I can't understand why and where its subjunctive sense is.

Moreover, the literal meaning of *satis* is **sufficient** or **sufficiently** and regarding to *satis* is not ablative, it likely must be adverb. But none of them translate it **sufficiently** or **adequately** or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my version it was wrote **sit**. 
Today I saw other versions have recorded it **fit**.
By **fit** the meaning is understandable.
The origin of fault is that **s** is wrote very similarly to **f** in Latin manuscripts.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much everything put forward in other answers is correct in its way. I'm just a bit surprised that none has rendered the subjunctive by 'would', as in:

*As would be obvious to anyone attentive enough*

Answer (score 0):

It's subjunctive because it is hypothetical. It is not a particular person paying attention: there might not be anybody paying attention at all. But *if* somebody pays sufficient attention, *then* it will be obvious to them.

I'm not certain about *satis*, but I would take it as an adverb.

Answer (score 0):

The translations are not literal, but they convey the message well.
The adverb *satis* modifies the participle *attendens*, leading to "someone who pays enough attention".
Shirley and Boyle get the nuance, whereas the other two translate *satis* in a weaker form.
In this context *satis* means essentially the same as "carefully" — but not if some other kind of word was modified.

There is no specific person who pays attention.
Latin often uses conjunctive when referring to an indefinite person.
If you want, you can read it as a conditional: "in case anyone is paying enough attention, it will be clear to them".

The conjunctive also finds its way to indefinite relative clauses.
For example:

> *Sunt qui sic dicant.*
>   There are people who say so. (But I won't or can't name any!)

I doubt that Spinoza meant *sit* to be a wish or a potential conjunctive.
And the translators all agree: it is translated as a factual statement.
Using "will be" instead of "is" is just a matter of idiomatic English in my opinion.

Here is a more literal translation (which is worse English):

> *ut satis attendenti sit manifestum*
>   as is clear to anyone who pays enough attention